# How to receive bytes from SPI with interrupts using HAL on STM32?

Tags: stm32, spi, interrupts, hal-library

**Background**

I am trying to make a SPI connection between two STM32F103C8T6's.

**Measurements**

According to my logic analyzer I get a signal that looks ok (sending 10 bytes with values 0x55):

[image]

**Results**

My receiver's callback function for RX Complete also stops in the breakpoint (last line in code below):

```
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
  if (hspi1.RxXferCount == 10)
```

**Problem**

I sent 10 bytes, however, the RxXferCount has value 0. Instead, RxXferSize has value 10, but pRxBuffPtr is empty.

**Question**

How can I receive the correct bytes?

**Values from the register SPI1 and variable hspi1**

[image]

[image]

**Relevant code**

Initialization (using a GPIO for defining Master and Slave):

```
/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12) == GPIO_PIN_SET ? 
    SPI_MODE_MASTER : SPI_MODE_SLAVE);
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

Main function:

```
int main(void)
{
   ...
   MX_SPI1_Init();
   ...

   _transmitter = (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12) == GPIO_PIN_SET ? 
                  SPI_MODE_MASTER : SPI_MODE_SLAVE);

   while (1)
   {
      if (_transmitter)
      {
      uint8_t data[] = { 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
                         0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55 };
          HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi1, data, 10);
      }
      else
      {
         HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi1, _spi_data, 10);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling stupid, but found the answer. Just want to mention it for others:

The result is NOT inside the argument hsp (.pRxBuffPtr) of the interrupt handler

```
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
```

but in the variable _spi_data provided by the receive command:

```
HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi1, _spi_data, 10);
```